# Probability in two throws of $3$ indistinguishable dice

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that two throws with three dice each will show
the same configuration if the dice are INDISTINGUISHABLE?

I reasoned in the following:
The number of possible outcome of 1 throw of $3$ indistinguishable dice are:
(I model the problem as balls and sticks: I have $3$ balls and $7$ sticks of which only $5$ sticks can move)
$$|\Omega|=\binom{8}{5}$$

Therefore after the first throw, treating the dice as indistinguishable, there will be only $1$ outcome of the second throw that will exactly match the outcome of the first throw.
Then the probability should be $$
P=\frac{1}{|\Omega|}\simeq0.01785$$

The Feller book report as a solution 
$$P=\frac{83}{3888}\simeq0.02134$$ 
and I cannot understand where I make mistakes

Comment: @Kaish

What book is that, may I ask, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conceptual mistake is in assuming that all outcomes are equally likely.

The outcome 1,1,1 is unlikely, because it can only happen one way. It has probability $(1/6)^3$

The outcome 1,1,2 is more likely because there are three different ways it can occur, because in this problem 1,1,2 is the same as 1,2,1 and 2,1,1. This result has probability $3(1/6)^3$, etc.

That should be enough for you to rework the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in implicitly assuming that the underlying outcomes of a single throw of the three dice are equally likely.  They are not.  For example, it is more likely you will observe $\{1,2,3\}$ than you might observe $\{1,1,1\}$.  So, the probability that the second throw will match the first is higher if the first throw contains three distinct values, compared to the case where the first throw shows duplicate values.

Try a simpler version of the problem with two dice instead of three.  Enumerate all the outcomes and the probability of those outcomes:  so for example, $\Pr[T_1 = \{1,1\}] = 1/36$, $\Pr[T_1 = \{1,2\}] = 1/18$, etc. where $T_1$ is the set of values obtained from the first throw.  Then calculate the probability that $T_1 = T_2$.  Then extend that solution to the case with three dice.