# Probability that two throws with three dice each will show the same configuration if the dice are indistinguishable

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question was asked couple of times here. First [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090565/probability-in-two-throws-of-3-indistinguishable-dice) and second [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099958/feller-question-on-two-throws-of-three-dice).

But unfortunately, I couldn't really understand that logic.

Since the dice are indistinguishable, there are only 41 ways of getting different results in the first throw of three dice. These are

All distinct (20)

`(1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,2,6), (1,3,4), (1,3,5), (1,3,6), (1,4,5), (1,4,6), (1,5,6), (2,3,4), (2,3,5), (2,3,6), (2,4,5), (2,4,6), (2,5,6), (3,4,5), (3,4,6), (3,5,6), (4,5,6)`

Two repetition (30)

`(1,2,2), (1,3,3), (1,4,4), (1,5,5), (1,6,6), (2,1,1), (2,3,3), (2,4,4), (2,5,5), (2,6,6), (3,1,1), (3,2,2), (3,4,4), (3,5,5), (3,6,6), (4,1,1), (4,2,2), (4,3,3), (4,5,5), (4,6,6), (5,1,1), (5,2,2), (5,3,3), (5,4,4), (5,6,6), (6,1,1), (6,2,2), (6,3,3), (6,4,4), (6,5,5)`

Three repetition (6)

`(1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4), (5,5,5), (6,6,6)`

Thus we got total of 56 distinct ways of arranging the first throw of the dice. Now the second throw should exactly match the first throw. For each of the first throw, this can happen only way. So the probability has to be $\frac{56}{6^6}$.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Those outcomes are not equally likely

Comment: Physically find two identical coins, and flip them: you will find that getting two heads happens in about $\frac14$ of attempts while your argument would suggest about $\frac13$ of attempts

Comment: If you throw `1,2,3` first you have 6 throws that will repeat the configuration. If `1,2,2` only three will do, and if `1,1,1` only one throw will do it. You have to weigh them by probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $20$ all distinct "configurations" correspond to $20 \times 3! = 120$ actually different throws.

The $30$ from your second group correspond to $30 \times 3 = 90$ actually different throws.

(check $120 + 90 + 6 = 216 = 6^3$)

Call the event that their the same configuration in the end $S$, and call the groups **I,II,III**. If the first throw is from **I** we have $\frac{6}{216}$ chance to repeat the configuration. If from **II**, that is $\frac{3}{216}$, and from **III**, only $\frac{1}{216}$ so that (conditioning on the event that the first throw is in the respective group):

$$P(S) = P(S|I)P(I)+ P(S|II)P(II) + P(S|III)P(III)=
  \frac{6}{216}\frac{120}{216} + \frac{3}{216}\frac{90}{216} + \frac{1}{216}\frac{6}{216} \simeq .0213$$